# Reopen file using office JS

Tags: office-js, office-addins, powerpoint-addins, javascript-api-for-office

Is it possible to reopen the already open file by discarding unsaved changes using office JS. According to the office API we don't have any open method. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/excel-add-ins-workbooks

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid that there is no way to do this with the Office JavaScript Library.